# Phppowerpoint Save Location?

Tags: php, phppowerpoint

I successfully create a ppt file using phpPowerpoint..

how can I change the save location?I want to save the file to other folder

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Type the new path, overwriting the existing location?

Comment: are you want to save the file two diffrent location at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify the filename in the call to save

```
$objPPTXWriter->save('filename.pptx');
```

simply specify a directory path as well

```
$objPPTXWriter->save('/path/to/my/directory/filename.pptx');
```